# Windows - getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config; exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have the problem with new ***Android Emulator 27.0.2***. Emulator won't starts. First launch of emu is successful after emulator sdk reinstall, but every second launch is unsuccessful.

---

*Cold boot* of virtual device not helps, *Emulated performance:* *Graphics: **Software - GLES 2.0*** option change at virtual device configuration not helps. Video driver for Intel HD 4400 is latest, reinstall not helps.

- `9:02    Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!`
- `9:02    Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!`
- `9:02    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.`
- `9:02    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions for me was to change ***buildToolsVersion*** for *current version*. In my case for:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
}
```

in app-level **`build.gradle`**