# Android-studio 1073741511 (0xC0000139)

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have a problem with emulator in android studio. Tried to install all tools, reinstall android studio and still not working. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901287/windows-7-android-emulator-27-0-2-getgles2extensionstring-could-not-find-gles

Comment: Still not working