# Emulator Failed to Start "OpenGLES emulation failed to initialized"

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I've been struggling with trying to launch android emulator but no success yet. I've updated the graphic card driver and done every possible solution out there but to no avail. For some reason with the new update there is something wrong needs to be fixed.

**Here is the screen of the errors**

[image]

[image]

Comment: check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901287/windows-7-android-emulator-27-0-2-getgles2extensionstring-could-not-find-gles

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the renderer failed to initialize. The solution currently is to try another renderer. Can you also try from command line with -gpu host, -gpu angle_indirect and -gpu swiftshader_indirect?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error using `Android emulator version 30.2.5.0 (build_id 6953278) (CL:N/A)` on `Debian 9`

when running `Api 28 x86` in headless mode (kvm enabled) with `emulator @a9 -wipe-data -no-window -no-audio -verbose -no-boot-anim -gpu off`

installing `libgl1-mesa-dev` from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Linux)

`apt install libgl1-mesa-dev`